# SQL query showing which entries lack rows defined in another table (exception report)

Tags: sql, postgresql

Using postgres I am trying to write a query that will show me which devices do not have all access-list entries defined on them.

The table `net_schema.acl_ssh` defines the master list of ACL entries that all devices should have:

| addr |
| --- |
| 10.10.10.10 |
| 20.20.20.20 |
| 30.30.30.30 |

The table `net_config.acl` contains the ACL entries that each device has:

| hostname | acl_id | src_addr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| sw01 | ssh | 10.10.10.10 |
| sw01 | ssh | 30.30.30.30 |
| sw02 | ssh | 10.10.10.10 |
| sw02 | ssh | 20.20.20.20 |
| sw02 | ssh | 30.30.30.30 |

The table `net_inv.master` is my inventory table of all devices:

| hostname | ip |
| --- | --- |
| sw01 | 192.168.1.1 |
| sw02 | 192.168.1.2 |
| sw03 | 192.168.1.3 |

The query should return device "sw01" since it is missing entry "20.20.20.20" and "sw03" since it's missing all ACL entries.

Answer (score 1):

I would blow out the `hostname` and `src_addr` combinations with a `cross join` and then use an `except` to find the missing records:

```
with needed as (
  select m.hostname, 'ssh' as acl_id, s.addr as src_addr
    from net_inv.master m
         cross join net_schema.acl_ssh s
)
select hostname, acl_id, src_addr from net_schema.acl
except
select hostname, acl_id, src_addr from needed;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! Looks like maybe a typo on the cross join line? Table reference there should be `net_schema.acl_ssh` to pull from the master list of ACL entries right? After adjusting that I am getting this error: 
```
ERROR:  each EXCEPT query must have the same number of columns
LINE 8: select * from needed;
```

Comment: @refriedjello Sounds like `net_schema.acl` has more columns than what you showed.  I have edited my answer to fix the typo and explicitly specify the columns to compare.

Answer (score 1):

I usually shy away from `select distinct`, but this seems like a reasonable use case if ever there was one.

I'm effectively using the left join to find entities where an inner join would fail.

```
select distinct
  i.hostname
from
  net_inv.master i
  cross join net_schema.acl_ssh s
  left join net_config.acl a on
    i.hostname = a.hostname and
    s.addr = a.src_addr
where
  a.hostname is null
```

For some background/explanation, this query gives you the full output, so you can see why the where condition followed by distinct narrows it down to the ones missing entries:

```
select *
from
  net_inv.master i
  cross join net_schema.acl_ssh s
  left join net_config.acl a on
    i.hostname = a.hostname and
    s.addr = a.src_addr
```